# How to make 10 ImageView's with 10 different border corner radius with just 1 GradientDrawable xml resource

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, xml-drawable

In an Android application,
How to make **10 ImageView's** with **10 different border corner radius** for each ImageView with just **1 GradientDrawable xml** resource (Not 10 different GradientDrawable xml resources)

It seems I should use **setCornerRadius** with different values for every ImageView but The point is If I setCornerRadius for ImageView2, then CornerRadius for ImageView1 is effected too and If I setCornerRadius for ImageView3, then CornerRadius for ImageView2 and ImageView1 are effected too and so on

Comment: You have to set corner radius for each and every image view.

Comment: So you mean there is no way but utilizing 10 GradientDrawable xml resource? It's strange cause .setStroke does not have such a problem and with just 1 GradientDrawable xml resource I can have 10 different strokes for the ImageView's

Comment: like `.setStroke()` , you can also set `.setCornerRadius()`, but you have to set for all image view not only single image view.

Comment: Yes I set (Stroke and CornerRadius) for all image views not only single image view and there is no problem with Stroke but CornerRadius has the problem I mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply create the gradient drawable from the java code like below-

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
drawable.setStroke(width, Color.RED);
drawable.setCornerRadius(8);
```

And set the drawable to imageview like below

```
        imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Sorry but the reply has nothing to do with the question!